# Getting error in accessing session variable in zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-session

I am using session container and store the arrays in a session. When i logged in then on the first time it give me undefined variable when i refresh the same page then it is working why?

```
    $container = new Container('user');
    $container->accesData=$data;
```

where **$data** is an array.

in my view i am accessing this session container as

```
    $container = new Container('user');
    $accessData=$container->accesData;
```

on the first time it give me an error while refreshing the same working fine why?

Recently i checked my project.

Actually what is happening?

I am performing logging from the login module after that i collect an assoc array and save it into the session from the module Case its working fine from till this stage and redirecting to the account module but the array which i store earlier is lost for the one time when i refresh the same its working inside account module. I don't know what is going on. Any one help me please?

Comment: This is because the session is being destroyed as soon as you close the browser. session.cache_expire = 0.

Comment: thanx for reply.But i am destroying the session by the following code  $container = new Container('user');
 $container->getManager()->getStorage()->clear('user');

Comment: It sounds like a timing issue. For example, the Container::accessData is set after the view is rendered. On page reload/refresh, the Container::accessData would be available. If this isn't the case, can you post an example using the ZF2 Skeleton Application?

Comment: @Chad Lad You are absolutely right.What is the solution for this?

Comment: @Chad Lad Please help me to resolve this problem?